# Django Templates: Output count of Filtered Through Relationship Attached Objects

Tags: django, templates

I have a model, "project" with a m2m thru relationship to "design".

```
class Project(models.model):
    ...
    desings = models.ManyToManyField(Design, through="ProjectDesign")
    ...

class ProjectDesigns(models.model):
    ...

class Design(models.model):
    ...
    published = models.BooleanField(default=Falase)
    ...
    def isPublished(self):
        if self.isPublished:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I'm passing the project instance in my context. I want to output the number of attached designs in the template, essentially something like:

```
{% project.designs.isPublished.count %}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this from the Template code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do it is:

```
class Project(models.model):
    ...
    desings = models.ManyToManyField(Design, through="ProjectDesign")
    ...

    def design_count(self):
        return self.desings.filter(desings__published=True)
```

and in the template

```
{% if project.design_count %}
```

The other way is, you can write a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) for `Design` model which returns only the published designs. Then your query would be as simple as

```
{% if project.desings.all %}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I needed. I was about 1/2 way there when I read your answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. You'll have to do this in the view. It's not the counting that's the problem, it's the filtering. First get all published projects in the context, then you can use |length in the template.

Comment: I was thinking there may not be a way to do this without adding code to the view, but karthikr's method worked.